# Sequelize upsert fails in SQL Server

Tags: node.js, sql-server, sequelize.js

Here I need to add a json like below into the SQL Server database using sequlize with a node.js backend.

```
[
   {
      "id":2,
      "name":"akjnsd",
      "description":"ijhoas",
      "order_num":0,
      "createdAt":"2018-10-02T04:33:13.432Z",
      "updatedAt":"2018-10-02T04:33:13.432Z",
      "columnId":1
   },
   {
      "id":1,
      "name":"Seting up environment",
      "description":"Need to discuss",
      "order_num":1,
      "createdAt":"2018-10-02T03:22:50.212Z",
      "updatedAt":"2018-10-02T03:22:50.212Z",
      "columnId":1
   }
]

    await models.Card.bulkCreate(newColumnCards,
    {
      fields:["order_num", "columnId"] ,
      updateOnDuplicate: ["order_num", "columnId"]
    } );
```

Also above code snippet is using to do my task. So here order_num, columnId is changing and need to update all these updated values in SQL Server database as well as to insert if a particular id is not in the Card table(A bulk upsert).

But I am getting below error saying bulk update is not supported. So is it can be figured out or is there any other solution?

> Error: mssql does not support the 'updateOnDuplicate' option.

Note: I am using SQL Server 2017. I went through this type of questions through stackoverflow. But could not find a specific answer for this.

**If does not support, is there any way to implement Bulk Update on sql server?**

Answer (score 0):

SQL Server does not support the `ON DUPLICATE KEY` feature so this Sequelize option cannot be used - it only works with MySQL.

https://github.com/sequelize/sequelize/issues/8766#issuecomment-350425464

http://docs.sequelizejs.com/class/lib/model.js~Model.html#static-method-bulkCreate

Comment: is there any way to implement at least bulk update feature?

Comment: @rohit_wason the original question was asking if it was supported, then it was apparently edited afterwards to ask for an alternative implementation. So basically, yes I just repeated what the errors says because it isn't supported on SQL Server which was the question.